# No JSON object could be decoded using python

Tags: python, json, sockets

I have the following code in my client:

```
        data = {"method": 2,"read": 3}
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(server_address)
        req = json.dumps(data)
        s.send(req)
```

and I am trying the following in my server:

```
        # Threat the socket as a file stream.
        worker = self.conn.makefile(mode="rw")
        # Read the request in a serialized form (JSON).
        request = worker.readline()
        result = json.loads(request)
        print(result)
```

and I am getting the `No JSON object could be decoded` error. I am using python 3.3. I cannot understand where is my mistake, it seems that the send method does not send an json object. Any idea?

`Edit`: I fixed the JSON format, the problem now is `<class 'TypeError'>: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'` on the server and `s.send(req)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface` on the client

Comment: Because that's **not** valid JSON.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using python 3, in which case, among other things you need to encode your data into bytes. Sockets cannot directly send python3 strings

Comment: @Max thanx max, that was the problem

Comment: I will add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using python 3, judging by the errors.

You'll need to encode your data into bytes.  Sockets cannot directly send python3 strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON isn't valid.  Put it through JSON lint to find the error.
http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Because that's **not** valid JSON.

You can look at [json.org](http://json.org) for the complete spec, and also always use [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to check your JSON.

JSON is made up of key/value pairs. Keys are always strings and must be double quoted. Numeric values are not quoted.

```
{"method":2, "2":3}
```

**Edit due to OP changing question:** The above was merely showing the valid *JSON* ... you of course would need it to be a **string** in your program to do anything with it (like send it over a socket).

```
data = '{"method": 2,"read": 3}'
```